# Difference between event object and condition variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, synchronization

What is the difference between event objects and condition variables?
I am asking in context of WIN32 API.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Event objects are kernel-level objects.  They can be shared across process boundaries, and are supported on all Windows OS versions.  They can be used as their own standalone locks to shared resources, if desired.  Since they are kernel objects, the OS has limitations on the number of available events that can be allocated at a time.

Condition Variables are user-level objects.  They cannot be shared across process boundaries, and are only supported on Vista/2008 and later.  They do not act as their own locks, but require a separate lock to be associated with them, such as a critical section.  Since they are user- objects, the number of available variables is limited by available memory.  When a Conditional Variable is put to sleep, it automatically releases the specified lock object so another thread can acquire it.  When the Conditional Variable wakes up, it automatically re-acquires the specified lock object again.

In terms of functionality, think of a Conditional Variable as a logical combination of two objects working together - a [keyed event](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/11/28/windows-keyed-events-critical-sections-and-new-vista-synchronization-features/) and a lock object.  When the Condition Variable is put to sleep, it resets the event, releases the lock, waits for the event to be signaled, and then re-acquires the lock.  For instance, if you use a critical section as the lock object, `SleepConditionalVariableCS()` is similar to a sequence of calls to `ResetEvent()`, `LeaveCriticalSection()`, `WaitForSingleObject()`, and `EnterCriticalSection()`.  Whereas if you use a SRWL as the lock, `SleepConditionVariableSRW()` is similar to a sequence of calls to `ResetEvent()`, `ReleaseSRWLock...()`, `WaitForSingleObject()`, and `AcquireSRWLock...()`.

Comment: I don't get it, if a CS contains an event inside it, then how can you claim it's limited by available memory instead of by the number of available events in the system?

Comment: I did not say a CS contains an *ACTUAL* event object, what I did say is "technically, that is not what a Conditional Variable actually does internally", IOW it only ACTS like it uses an event, but it likely does not.  The details of how a CS waits are private to the OS's implementation. In the case of `SleepConditionVariableCS()`, for instance, it is more likely using `SleepEx()` instead, and woken up by timeout or an APC from `WakeConditionVariable()`.  I updated by answer to reflect that.

Comment: After reading walkingbear's answer, the implementation is likely using a [keyed event](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/11/28/windows-keyed-events-critical-sections-and-new-vista-synchronization-features/) as the waitable object.  That way, multiple CSs are using sharing a single kernel event object that is always available and can be waited on by separate threads individually.

Comment: A CS does seem to contain an actual semaphore (see the definition of `RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION` in `WinNT.h`), but I just realized I misread your answer--you were talking about CV, not CS. Indeed, a keyed event is most likely. The CS definitely needs an event or semaphore or something so it can enter a kernel wait if need be, but the CV does not seem to.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant CV, not CS.  And yes, a CS (not a CV) can contain a dedicated event object (allocated when needed), or the global keyed event if a dedicated event cannot be allocated.

Answer (score 2):

They are very similar, but event objects work across process boundaries, whereas condition variables do not. From the [MSDN documentation on condition variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682052%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Condition variables are user-mode
>   objects that cannot be shared across
>   processes.

From the [MSDN documentation on event objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682655%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Threads in other processes can open a
>   handle to an existing event object by
>   specifying its name in a call to the 
>   OpenEvent  function.

Comment: No, Remy Lebeau is closer to truth. Condition Variable is something that was recently imported from Unix into Windows. Event object is a pale imitation of Condition. In fact, it's nontrivial to implement Condition Var given only Event Object and Mutex. See http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/win32-cv-1.html

Answer (score 1):

The most significant difference is the Event object is a kernel object and can be shared across processes as long as it is alive when processes/threads are trying to acquire, on the contrary, Condition variable is a user mode object which is light(only has same size as a pointer and has nothing additional to be released after using it) and has better performance.

Typically, condition variable is often used along with locks, since we need to keep data synchronized properly. When considering Condition Variable, we treat it like keyed events which was improved since Vista.

Joe duffy has a blog post http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/11/28/windows-keyed-events-critical-sections-and-new-vista-synchronization-features/ that explained more detailed information.