# Product/Consumer - what is the optimal signalling pattern

Tags: c++, windows, performance, synchronization

I am building a high performance app that needs two function to synchronise threads

```
void wake_thread(thread)

void sleep_thread(thread)
```

The app has a single thread (lets call it C) that may fall asleep with a call to sleep_thread. There are multiple threads that will call wake_thread. When wake_thread returns it MUST guarantee that C is either running or will be woken. wake_thread must NEVER block.

The easy way is of course to do use a synchronisation event like this:

```
hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, TRUE, NULL);

void wake_thread(thread) {

  SetEvent(hEvent);
}
```

And:

```
void sleep_thread(thread)
{
  WaitForSingleObject(hEvent);
}
```

This provides the desired semantics and is free of race conditions for the scenario (There is only one thread waiting, but multiple that can signal). I included it here to show what I am trying to tune.

HOWEVER, I am wondering there is a faster way under Windows for this very specific scenario. **wake_thread** may be called a lot, even when C is not sleeping. This causes a lot of calls to SetEvent that do nothing. Would there be a faster way to use manual reset event and reference counters to make sure SetEvent is only called when there is actually something to set.

Every CPU cycle counts in this scenario.

Comment: `SetEvent()` when no one is actually waiting is remarkably fast.  It will be much slower when the thread is actually waiting (in other words, don't bother with this premature optimization).  If you really want to be fast, don't sleep and burn 100% CPU.

Comment: Hi Chad. It is indeed fast. The code I have is already fully functional, so I am looking to make it faster. I cant afford to burn CPU, I need the cycles to be as low as possible

Comment: In that case, I would say that you won't be able to do anything faster by adding _more_ work to do to track this.  The overhead will almost certainly outweigh any perceived gains.  When an event is already signalled, `SetEvent()` does nothing, so there is virtually no performance penalty for calling it when no objects are actively waiting on it.

Comment: [Difference between event object and condition variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1215441/1888362)

Comment: You could set a flag when the thread is sleeping and only call SetEvent if the flag is set.  You'd need to use InterlockedCompareExchange or similar to avoid race conditions, but these are very fast operations.

Comment: Hi Harry. Setting the flag is one option, however, this leads to a race condition when I wake up again and clear the flag. However, I think there might be a way to clear the Signalled state in sleep_thread and mix this up with an atomic op to get a race free implementation

Comment: Sergmat: I am familiar with condition variables too, but they dont solve the problem of trying to avoid a kernel mode transition and behind the scenes, they are still going to need a barrier. Ideally, this would be done with atomics and Event objects together.

Comment: Do you also have a critical section?  A queue?  You only want to SetEvent when the queue transitions from empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this (apart from making sure it compiles) but I think this should do the trick.  It was, admittedly, a bit trickier than I at first thought.  Note that there are some obvious optimizations you could make; I've left it in unoptimized form for clarity and to aid any debugging that may be necessary.  I've also omitted error checking.

```
#include <intrin.h>

HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
__declspec(align(4)) volatile LONG thread_state = 2;
    // 0 (00): sleeping
    // 1 (01): sleeping, wake request pending
    // 2 (10): awake, no additional wake request received
    // 3 (11): awake, at least one additional wake request

void wake_thread(void)
{
    LONG old_state;

    old_state = _InterlockedOr(&thread_state, 1);
    if (old_state == 0)
    {
        // This is the first wake request since the consumer thread
        // went to sleep.  Set the event.

        SetEvent(hEvent);
        return;
    }
    if (old_state == 1)
    {
        // The consumer thread is already in the process of being woken up.
        // Any items added to the queue by this thread will be processed,
        // so we don't need to do anything.

        return;
    }
    if (old_state == 2)
    {
        // This is an additional wake request when the consumer thread
        // is already awake.  We've already changed the state accordingly,
        // so we don't need to do anything else.

        return;
    }
    if (old_state == 3)
    {
        // The consumer thread is already awake, and already has an
        // additional wake request registered, so we don't need to do
        // anything.

        return;
    }
    BigTrouble();
}

void sleep_thread(void)
{
    LONG old_state;

    // Debugging only, remove this test in production code.
    // The event should never be signaled at this point.

    if (WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 0) != WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
        BigTrouble();
    }

    old_state = _InterlockedAnd(&thread_state, 1);
    if (old_state == 2)
    {
        // We've changed the state from "awake" to "asleep".
        // Go to sleep.

        WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);

        // We've been buzzed; change the state to "awake"
        // and then reset the event.

        if (_InterlockedExchange(&thread_state, 2) != 1)
        {
            BigTrouble();
        }
        ResetEvent(hEvent);
        return;
    }
    if (old_state == 3)
    {
        // We've changed the state from "awake with additional
        // wake request" to "waking".  Change it to "awake"
        // and then carry on.

        if (_InterlockedExchange(&thread_state, 2) != 1)
        {
            BigTrouble();
        }
        return;
    }
    BigTrouble();
}
```

Basically this uses a manual-reset event and a two-bit flag to reproduce the behaviour of an automatic-reset event.  It may be clearer if you draw a state diagram.  The thread safety depends on the rules about which of the functions is allowed to make which transitions, and also on when the event object is allowed to be signaled.

As an editorial: I think it is separating the synchronization code into the wake_thread and sleep_thread functions that makes things a bit awkward.  It would probably be more natural, slightly more efficient, and almost certainly clearer if the synchronization code were moved into the queue implementation.

Comment: Hi Harry. Yes, I believe this one does it (had to walk the state diagram)!... I will test it and let you know. Voted as answer

Answer (score 2):

`SetEvent()` will introduce some latency as it does have to make a system call (`sysenter` triggers the switch from user to kernel mode) for the object manager to check the state of the event and dispatch it (via a call to `KeSetEvent()`). I think that the time of the system call might be considered to be acceptable even in your circumstances, but that is speculation. Where most of the latency is likely going to be introduced is on the receiving side of the event. In other words, it takes time to wake a thread from a [`WaitFor*Object()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) than it does to signal the event. The Windows scheduler tries to help getting to the thread sooner by giving a priority "boost" to a thread that is having a wait return, but that boost only does so much.

In order to get around this, you should be sure that you are only waiting when it is necessary to do so. The typical method to do this is, in your consumer, when you are signaled to go, consume every work item that you can without waiting on the event again, then when done make your call to `sleep_thread()`

I should point out that `SetEvent()`/`WaitFor*Object()` is almost surely faster than everything short of eating 100% CPU and even then it may be quicker as a result of the contention on whatever locking object needs to protect your shared data.

Normally, I would recommend the use of a [ConditionVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I have not tested its performance compared to your technique. I have a suspicion that it may be slower since it also has the overhead of entering CRITICAL_SECTION object. You may have to measure the performance different -- when in doubt, measure, measure, measure.

The only other thing that I can think to say is that MS does acknowledge that dispatching and waiting on events can be slow, especially when it is performed repeatedly. In order to get around this, they changed the [`CRITICAL_SECTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object to try for a number of times in user mode to acquire the lock before actually waiting on the event. They call this the [spin count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). While I wouldn't recommend it, you may be able to do something similar.

Comment: Hi Sean. Thanks for the detailed answer. The kernel mode transition is exactly my worry here. What I am building is a queue (already lockless on push/pop) and the C thread DOES empty the queue fully on wake (that is already optimised). The SetEvent is showing up a clear consumer of CPU resources. I have upvoted your reply, but not yet marked it as an answer as I am still missing a detailed algorithm for an alternative solution.

Comment: Knowing that you have indeed profiled your code and know that `SetEvent()` is the culprit, the only solution that I can offer up is changing the work items that are queued to be more substantial. It seems that if `SetEvent()` is being called enough to be problematic, work items should either be larger and fewer, or possibly grouped up before signaling the event. Without the specifics of your algorithm and its requirements, I can't say how feasible that is, though.

Comment: Making the work items substantial would be great. Unfortunately, I dont have that luxury in the code. My issue is that I have a LOT of incoming threads that add items to the work queue, some queue a lot, some queue a little. But each one of them must guarantee that the other end of the queue (the C popper) will eventually pop, even if the system has gone quiet. This leads to a situation where I can "miss one signal" at the very end before quiecing the channel

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
void consumer_thread(void)
{
   while(1)
   {
      WaitForSingleObject(...);

      // Consume all items from queue in a thread safe manner (e.g. critical section)
   }
}

void produce()
{
   bool queue_was_empty = ...; // in a thread safe manner determine if queue is empty
   // thread safe insertion into queue ...
   // These two steps should be done in a way that prevents the consumer 
   // from emptying the queue in between, e.g. a spin lock.  
   // This guarantees you will never miss the "edge"
   if( queue_was_empty )
   {
      SetEvent(...);
   }
}
```

The general idea is to only SetEvent on the **transition** from empty to full.  If the threads have the same priority Windows should let the producer(s) keep running and therefore you can minimize your number of SetEvent calls per queue insertions.  I've found this arrangement (between threads of equal priority) to give the best performance (at least under Windows XP and Win7, YMMV).

Comment: Guy, this one is racy. The check between queue_was_empty and the SetEvent could be raced by the setting of the empty bit and you get a "lost signal". Unfortunately, I dont have the luxury of knowing if the queue is full or not either. I have a lockless Lamport queue between the producer and consumer, and the head/tail required to know if the queue is empty or not isnt  protected by a lock.

Comment: @ThomasKejser: It's true that someone else could be inserting into the queue in the mean time but SetEvent will get called exactly once per empty queue if the **test and the insert are done atomically**.  As long as the consumer always empties the queue before waiting the system is safe.  There's a possibility of a Set generated where it's not needed but the consumer will see an empty queue and wait again.  (Maybe what you're missing is that the event remains set even if the other thread isn't in `WaitForSingleObject`).

Comment: @GuySirton: If I've understood correctly, the problem is that the lockless Lamport queue algorithm doesn't allow you to test and insert atomically.  I suspect you could use InterlockedIncrement and InterlockedDecrement to keep track of the queue count in a thread-safe manner but I'm not sure; there might be race conditions related to the gap between the actual queue operation and the increment/decrement.  I'd need to see an implementation to decide.